# Regular expression by groups

Tags: python, regex

there is a file that has the form:

```
FY4A-_AGRI--_N_DISK_1047E_L1-_FDI-_MULT_NOM_20191025000000_20191025001459_4000M_V0001.HDF
```

The regular expression has the following form

```py
/^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}[-]{1}[_]{1}[A-Z]{4}[-]{2}[_]{1}[A-Z]{1}[_]{1}[A-Z]{4}[_]{1}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[_]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[-]{1}[_]{1}[A-Z]{3}[-]{1}[_]{1}[A-Z]{4}[_]{1}[A-Z]{3}[_]{1}[0-9]{14}[_]{1}[0-9]{14}[_]{1}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[_]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}[.]{1}[A-Z]{3}$/
```

How do I make sure that everything was in groups?

I'd like to get something like that:

```py
(?P<ftype>[A-Z0-9]{5})      # band type of data file
            _[a-z]+                     # sat id
            _(?P<date>\d{8})           # acq date
            _(?P<time>\d{7})           # granule start time UTC
            _\d+                       # granule end time UTC
            _(?P<orbit>\d+)            # orbit number
            _\d+                       # file creation date/time
            _\w+.h5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as follows using `regex`.

```py
import re
s = 'FY4A-_AGRI--_N_DISK_1047E_L1-_FDI-_MULT_NOM_20191025000000_20191025001459_4000M_V0001.HDF'
re.findall(pattern, s)
```

**Output**:

```
[('FY4A',
  'AGRI',
  'N',
  'DISK',
  '1047E',
  'L1',
  'FDI',
  'MULT',
  'NOM',
  '20191025000000',
  '20191025001459',
  '4000M',
  'V0001',
  'HDF')]
```

#### Where Pattern Is:

```py
pattern = ["^([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1})", # FF0F
           "[-]{1}[_]{1}",                # -_
           "([A-Z]{4})",                  # FFFF
           "[-]{2}[_]{1}",                # --_
           "([A-Z]{1})",                  # F
           "[_]{1}",                      # _
           "([A-Z]{4})",                  # FFFF
           "[_]{1}", 
           "([0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1})", 
           "[_]{1}", 
           "([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})", 
           "[-]{1}[_]{1}", 
           "([A-Z]{3})", 
           "[-]{1}[_]{1}", 
           "([A-Z]{4})", 
           "[_]{1}", 
           "([A-Z]{3})", 
           "[_]{1}", 
           "([0-9]{14})", 
           "[_]{1}", 
           "([0-9]{14})", 
           "[_]{1}", 
           "([0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1})", 
           "[_]{1}", 
           "([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4})", 
           "[.]{1}", 
           "([A-Z]{3})$"]

pattern = ''.join(pattern)
```

Comment: If you enclose the pattern in () instead of [] then you don't need the end of line commas or the join statement

Comment: @HolyMackerel Thank you for pointing it out. However, my objective was to be able to write `#comments` next to each line so, the OP could make notes of what stands for what, if need be.

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest here that you just try doing a regex split on a set of delimiters which you were already using to define the groups in your pattern:

```
inp = "FY4A-_AGRI--_N_DISK_1047E_L1-_FDI-_MULT_NOM_20191025000000_20191025001459_4000M_V0001.HDF"
parts = re.split(r'[_.-]+', inp)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['FY4A', 'AGRI', 'N', 'DISK', '1047E', 'L1', 'FDI', 'MULT', 'NOM', '20191025000000',
 '20191025001459', '4000M', 'V0001', 'HDF']
```

You can easily access whichever group you want by using a regular Python list index.  Note this approach is cleaner and easier to maintain than such a verbose regex.

Answer (score 0):

The result is identical to previous options but the method is slightly different :

```
import re

inp = "FY4A-_AGRI--_N_DISK_1047E_L1-_FDI-_MULT_NOM_20191025000000_20191025001459_4000M_V0001.HDF"

inp = re.sub(r'-', '', inp)

pattern = re.findall(r'''   
                        ^([A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z])         # Comment1
                        _([A-Z]{4})                # Comment2
                        _([A-Z])                   # ...
                        _([A-Z]{4}) 
                        _(\d{4}[A-Z])
                        _([A-Z]\d)                         
                        _([A-Z]{3})                        
                        _([A-Z]{4})                        
                        _([A-Z]{3})                        
                        _(\d{8})0{6}                       
                        _(\d{8})\d{6}                      
                        _(\d{4}[A-Z])                      
                        _([A-Z]\d{4})\.([A-Z]{3})$         
                        ''', inp, re.VERBOSE)
```

This gaves me:

```
[('FY4A', 'AGRI', 'N', 'DISK', '1047E', 'L1', 'FDI', 'MULT', 'NOM', '20191025', '20191025', '4000M', 'V0001', 'HDF')]
```

You can then remove some groups to only catch parts you want. As I said it's not better, but this is to chop your regex into small pieces, hope it helps